# Squarified treemap algorithm for flat data-sets?

Tags: algorithm, treemap

At the moment I use the slice & dice approach:

- get the list of values and labels
- calculate the sum of all values
- calculate the ratios by dividing every value by the sum
- for every list item:

  - draw a box with `height=1` and `width=ratio`
  - draw the label on top of the box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me restate your question as I understood it.

You know the areas of a bunch of rectangles that you need to draw and fit into a square, and you'd like to do so with the rectangles not having extreme height/width ratios.  Each rectangle represents the portion of the total value taken by a given label.  The question is to figure out what the shape and positions of those rectangles should be such that they fit perfectly, and each has the required area.

You do not need a perfect answer.  Only one that is better than the current, which just slices the square into vertical strips.

Here is my suggestion.  Generalize to fitting rectangles in a targt rectangle.  (This lets us use recursion.)  Also I will assume that the labels have been sorted by area, with the largest first.  (Sorting is an easy step to add.)  Then figure out the placement of rectangles according to the following recursive rules:

1. If the first element in the list is more than 1/3 of the area, split the long side of your target rectangle into the first element, and everything else, then recursively fit everything else in the remainder.
2. Otherwise split your list into two, with the median of the area going into the first list.  Divide your target rectangle into two, one for the first list, one for the second.  Recursively fill each rectangle.

This should provide a fairly good division for your purposes with most data sets.  It should be fairly fast to compute, and only the very smallest rectangle can have a ratio more extreme than 3 to 1.

Comment: Thank you. But how do I calculate the sizes? For slice&dice I only multiply the width of a rectangle by the ratio.

Comment: @K.. The sizes are the ratios.